# Retrieving xpath from stored webelement variable

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using page object model. Here is XPath that I have written for Heading of the page and stored it in the **heading** WebElement variable:

```
@FindBy( xpath = "//div[@class='page-title category-title']")
private WebElement heading;`
```

My goal is to get or extract the XPath back from the element **heading**.
I have tried printing it but the result I am getting is, `System.out.println(heading)`

gave me:

```
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (4520a9a1-c58b-4b34-ae3e-48613e6e7005)] -> xpath: //div[@class='page-title category-title']]`
```

And my expectation is :

```
//div[@class='page-title category-title']
```

as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the class attribute of the element and create the xpath

```
String headingClass = heading.getAttribute("class");

String headingPath = "//div[@class='"+ headingClass + "']"
```

then use headingPath wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
String source = "[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (4520a9a1-c58b-4b34-ae3e-48613e6e7005)] -> xpath: //div[@class='page-title category-title']]";
System.out.println((source.substring(0, source.length() - 1).split("-> ")[1]));
//Output:
xpath: //div[@class='page-title category-title']
```

1. (source.substring(0, source.length() - 1) : this will remove the last element which is ']'(the last square bracket)
2. split("-> ")[1] : will split the string/element and return it's 1 element.

System.out.println(source.split("-> ")[1]);

Output:
xpath: //div[@class='page-title category-title']]

do you see the last ']'? that's the one I'm removing in the first step.

Comment: Welcome to the community! It's helpful to NOT just write code but add an explanation. You say this improves a previous answer..how? Why is this a better solution? It's recommended to review this: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: adding  one more split function " split("xpath:")[1]" at the end will remove the string "xpath:" 
output :  //div[@class='page-title category-title']

Comment: Thanks @SadhaNanda. I didn't do that because, I need that string as well incase if it's id, name, etc other than xpath.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want the output like this , but i can think of one way of getting you the class name instead of the whole xpath,

```
System.out.println(heading.getAttribute("class"));
```

which will give you result as **page-title category-title**

Then you can prefix & postfix with you xpath string if only you want the output like that, then again as i said, i don't know why you need output string like that,

```
System.out.println("//div[@class='"+heading.getAttribute("class")+"']");
```

Want to know out of curiosity, whats the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Why? In my experience, because ExpectedConditions only work with locators and not with existing webelements... It's kind of silly to redefine an   XPath if you already know the element.

Answer (score 0):

We will be splitting the string with the delimitor "xpath:"

```
String[] a = heading.toString().split("xpath:");

//The length will be 2
System.out.println("length"+a.length); 

// will print //div[@class='page-title category-title']
System.out.println(a[a.length-1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String source = "[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (4520a9a1-c58b-4b34-ae3e-48613e6e7005)] -> xpath: //div[@class='page-title category-title']]";

//Split your Source from "->"
String[] temp = source.split("-> ");

//Split your Source from ": "
String[] temp2 = temp[1].split(": ");

//Access first index to get locator name
String locator = temp2[0];

//Access Second index to get locator value
String value = temp2[1].substring(0,temp2[1].length()-1);
```

Comment: This really doesn't add anything to the existing answers to a several-year-old question, and is actually less efficient with the multiple split operations, for no apparent added value.